# How to interpret discrete Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, intuition

I am teaching myself about the Discrete Fourier Transform. For this reason, I am going over an example, and I would like to interpret the results, for which I have a hard time.

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^7$ where $x_n = \sin(\frac{\pi n}{4})$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ with $\frac{\pi}{4}$ intervals. After applying DFT to this sequence $x_n \xrightarrow[]{\text{DFT}} X_k$ we get the following values:

$$X_k = \begin{cases}
4i \quad \text{when $k = 7$} \\
-4i \quad \text{when $k = 2$} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I have plotted the sequence as a function of time and the resulting amplitudes:

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. By applying the DFT, we get values that could be completely imaginary. For this reason, we compute its norm to get a real value. What does the plain value of DFT tell us? Why doesn't the definition of DFT include taking the norm? (If you notice, I did not label the $y$-axis, since I was not sure what they are called - Are they called amplitudes for both?)
2. DFT gives a sequence that is a function of frequency. What is this function? Is there an explicit formula?
3. The result of the plot is somewhat unexpected for me. There are two peaks at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4}$, but $x_1 = x_3$ and $x_5 = x_7$. So why are $X_3 $ and $X_5$ just $0$?
4. Similarly, the maximum and minimum value in the sequence $x_2$ and $x_6$ are being mapped to $0$. Why does not DFT preserve maximum and minimum of the original sequence?

My goal by asking these questions is to build intuition, so if I see a sequence, I can create a reasonable picture of its DFT in my head. If you can provide explanations that can help with building intuition, please go for it.

Comment: It helps to know your background with other transforms as most people don't learn about the DFT first - what is your intuition with the regular Fourier transforms, either continuous or discrete time?

Comment: I just got started with Fourier Series and moved on to DFT. Other transforms are in my list to cover, but DFT is the first one.

Comment: Represent your transform with 2 vertical arrows accounting for two $\delta$ (Dirac ) peaks making the correspondence with the continuous Fourier transform of a sine. As said by Ninad Munshi, having a certain prior knowledge with continuous Fourier transform is (almost) a must.